# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'add_artist' matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.offsetbox import OffsetImage,AnnotationBbox

def get_flag(name):
    path = "flags/flags/{}.png".format(name)
    im = plt.imread(path)
    return im

def offset_image(name, ax, xy):
    img = get_flag(name)
    im = OffsetImage(img, zoom=0.72)
    im.image.axes = ax

    ab = AnnotationBbox(im, xy, frameon=False, xycoords='data', boxcoords="offset points", pad=0)

    ax.add_artist(ab)

ax = df.plot(kind='scatter',x='% of Ages 65+',y='COVID Fatality Rate', title='Correlation between % of Ages 65+ and COVID Fatality Rate')

for i, c in enumerate(df['Country']):
    offset_image(i, c, ax)

plt.show()
```

I'm annotating country flags instead of markers on a scatter plot. But AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'add_artist' shows up. How do I fix this?

Comment: in ```offset_images(i, c, ax)``` call, you've put ax as the 3rd parameter when it should be the 2nd.

Comment: so what should be the right structure of the offset_images?

Comment: I changed it already but the error now is ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: `def offset_image(name, xy, ax):` and `offset_image(i, c, ax)` should work

Answer (score 0):

You have two errors related with your `offset_image()`.

Fisrtly, as ewong and Phani Rithvij point out in the comment, the order of parameter you define in the `offset_image()` and the order how you call it are not the same.

Secondly, *xy* parameter in [AnnotationBbox](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/offsetbox_api.html#matplotlib.offsetbox.AnnotationBbox) needs to be a tuple or a list which represents a point in coordinates system. However, you only pass a value `c`.

Without changing how you define `offset_image()`, you only need to change how you call it like below:

```py
for i, c in enumerate(df['Country']):
    offset_image(i, ax, (i, c))
```